# Кто такие беты?

Tags: сленг

Сейчас в интернете человека, который вычитывает текст, называют "бета". Если честно, это слово мне очень режет слух. Есть редактор, есть корректор - их задача вычитывать тексты на наличие стилистических и грамматических ошибок.
Я понимаю, что "бета" происходит от "бета-ридер", мне совсем не нравится, что оно вытеснило понятие "вычитка" или "редактура", поскольку употребляют его те, кто слова "редактор" чаще всего даже не знают. Я обычно поправляю, но народ удивляется: "А что тут такого?"
Так вот, допустимо ли называть человека, делающего вычитку текста, "бета-ридером" или "бетой"?

Answer (score 2):

Бета-ридер
 - это не редактор и тем более не корректор. И тот и другой исправляют 
текст для улучшения его читабельности или грамотности. Бета же ничего не 
исправляет. В его задачу входит внимательно текст прочитать и донести до 
автора свое впечатление о тексте в целом, отметив его частные недостатки 
(незнакомое слово без пояснения, непрописана мотивация
 второстепенных персонажей и т. п.). Редактор, получив явную графоманию, 
может прочитать пару страниц и выкинуть рукопись за отсутствием 
перспектив ее публикации. Корректору все равно, о чем книга, если в 
тексте соблюдены все нормы правописания. Бета-ридер же, по-русски 
"читатель-испытатель", дочитывает произведение до конца и указывает автору 
недостатки, не исправляя их.

Подобными "вчитывателями" очень часто служат жены, родственники или 
друзья писателей, но если их литературному вкусу довериться нельзя, 
приходится прибегать к услугам бета-ридеров.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, что у знаменитого «Гарри Поттера» были свои бета-ридеры. Это офис-менеджер литературного агентства  Брайони Эванс и внештатный рецензент  Флер Хоул – профессиональный первый  чтец рукописей.

Изначально  «Гарри Поттер» оказался в мусорной корзине (агентство не занималось детскими книгами), но пластиковая черная папка, в которую он был запакован, во время обеденного перерыва привлекла внимание Брайони: «Мне стало любопытно, и я выудила ее из корзины».

Она прочитала первую главу, заинтересовалась ею и передала Флер для ознакомления.  Только после этого был запрошен полный текст книги,  и директор агентства,  после их восторженных отзывов,  лично ознакомился  с  рукописью (взял ее собой и прочел за один вечер).

Всё это происходило в 1995 году, а в 2000 году Джоанна Роллинг подарила Эванс книгу с дарственной надписью "Брайони - истинной первооткрывательнице Гарри Поттера".